# Selecting commits to send in a pull-request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked a project on GitHub. Being a pure Java source, I had to adapt it to turn it into an eclipse project before working on it. I made 3 commits to reflect these changes.

I then finished adapting the actual program, and I want to send a pull-request back to the developer requesting these changes.

My commit history is as follows:

- Commits #1, #3 and #4 are eclipse based and *should not* be sent.
- #2, #5, #6, #7 and #8 are source related and *should* be sent.

How do I send a pull-request omitting #1, #3 and #4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should have a separate branch of development for each of these features - "eclipse project" and "feature implementation". Then send a pull request for the "feature implementation" back to the source.

Since you have not done that, you can cut a branch called `feature` from the point where you cloned and `cherry-pick` commits 2, 5, 6, 7 and 8. Then send a pull request for this branch.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'll make sure to branch properly next time.

Comment: So you do the two different changes in two different branches.  But if you want to debug and test your "feature" change, then you have to have them together.  So how do you edit the "feature" changes without the "eclipse" changes?

Comment: You can always merge from `feature` into `eclipse`. I imagine that will be necessary too. The reason I'm suggesting that you keep them separate is so that you have one branch with changes (`feature`) that you can send back to upstream.